# Spring STS fails to run on windows 10 64bit

Tags: java, windows, spring

Running on windows 10 64bit, I downloaded the **Spring sts 3.8.2** from their website for 64bit windows and installed **JDK 1.8.0_111** and **JRE 1.8.0_111**.

JDK is added to environmental variables PATH.

when running the STS I end up with the following error message:

[image]

What I also don't understand is that in the task manager STS is marked as 32bit version although I downloaded the 64bit version:

[image]

and this is what I get for the java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Any idea what's going on with this ?

Comment: When you right click on the Spring STS icon is it using the same version of Java that corresponds to the one you have in your %PATH% which is being picked up on your command line? I'm thinking it does not and that is the problem.

Comment: @Richie thanks for the reply. what do you mean by the right click? are you talking about the STS.ini? STS.ini says ***Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8***

Comment: Right click on Spring STS and then select properties. From that I think you should be able to tell which version of Java it is using.

Comment: @Richie He asked you to be specific on what "Spring STS" means, so please clarify what you mean, because it is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Install Java **JRE** and **JDK** on same location in your PC.

Because **STS** looks for **JRE** and **JDK** to be installed at same location.

Or you can change STS configurations.

*But I'll recommend You to re-install the* **same versions** *of* **JRE** and **JDK** *at* **same location**.

Comment: I faced same issue, and it's 100% working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out that STS needs full JDK to work and gives this error when only JRE is present. I had to download NetBeans that comes with JDK. After that STS works without an issue.

[image: Netbeans download link.]